# Count Distinct Same Value in two column

Tags: mysql

I want to count distinct value that exist in 2 columns like

```
Column A    Column B
1             5
5             6
4             1
5             4
```

How can I get the answer : 4 as there are only four distinct values in both columns.

Can you please guide me how to apply in query (Distinct count in Club1 and Club2)

SELECT Count(DISTINCT registrationevent.RegistrationNo) AS TotalRegistration, Sum(If((registrationevent.Spouse = 1), 1, 0)) AS CoupleRegistration, Count(DISTINCT registration.Club) AS Club1, count(Distinct registration.SpouseClub) as Club2 FROM (registrationevent) JOIN registration ON registrationevent.RegistrationNo = registration.RegistrationNo

Comment: `count distinct same value` - Can you clarify this a little?

Comment: count distinct values from both column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: The specification "distinct value in both column jointly" isn't very clear.  Do you want to return 4 because there are four distinct values 1,4,5 and 6  that in appear in either A or B?  Or did you want to return 4 because there are four distinct (A,B) tuples  (1,5), (5,6), (4,1), (5,4).

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK union is distinct by itself:

```
SELECT A
FROM tab
UNION
SELECT B
FROM tab
```

or- as you seem to be interested in the count only:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
  (
    SELECT A
    FROM tab
  UNION
    SELECT B
    FROM tab
  ) AS C
```

Comment: Can you please guide me how to apply in this query (Distinct count in Club1 and Club2)



SELECT Count(DISTINCT registrationevent.RegistrationNo) AS TotalRegistration,
  Sum(If((registrationevent.Spouse = 1), 1, 0)) AS CoupleRegistration,
  Count(DISTINCT registration.Club) AS Club1,
  count(Distinct registration.SpouseClub) as Club2
FROM (registrationevent)
  JOIN registration ON registrationevent.RegistrationNo =
    registration.RegistrationNo

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select count(*)
from (
    select distinct * from t
) t
```

Comment: I want like this but some other count columns are there in which it affect like in the same table Registration, Gender and etc fields are there and I want to count all in same query

Comment: @Sanjeev - Use asterisk to select distinct of all the columns or if you want to select some of them, mention them explicitly in the subquery). Updated the answer.

Comment: Can you please guide me how to apply in this query (Distinct count in Club1 and Club2)



SELECT Count(DISTINCT registrationevent.RegistrationNo) AS TotalRegistration,
  Sum(If((registrationevent.Spouse = 1), 1, 0)) AS CoupleRegistration,
  Count(DISTINCT registration.Club) AS Club1,
  count(Distinct registration.SpouseClub) as Club2
FROM (registrationevent)
  JOIN registration ON registrationevent.RegistrationNo =
    registration.RegistrationNo